# trying to filter the array of objects ina better way

Tags: javascript

I have the array of objects as like this

```
var items = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'john'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'jane'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'zack'
}];

var names = items.map(function(item) {
  return item['name'];
});

console.log(names);
console.log(items);
```

its working fine, except, i want the output to be like this

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "names": ["john","zack",jane"]
    }
]
```

Comment: Where did that id (100634) come from?

Comment: "filtering" is neither what you are currently doing nor what the expected result is. Also, the expected result really cannot be derived from the input - the ID doesn't seem to be at all related to any part of the input.

Comment: i updated my question, it should be 1

Comment: Are you trying to just combine all of the possible names?
Or are you trying to group them by id and combine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an object to store the names for each id.

```js
let items = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'john'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'jane'
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'zack'
}];
let res = Object.values(
  items.reduce((acc, {id, name}) => {
    (acc[id] ??= {id, names: []}).names.push(name);
    return acc;
  }, {})
);
console.log(res);
```